# Changing the imported library's environment variable

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables, python-import, sidekit

I want to set the following environment variable

```
SIDEKIT = ”theano=true,theano_config=gpu,libsvm=true,mpi=false”
```

for the imported third-party library **SIDEKIT**.

Do I need to reinstall the package and change the line in setup?

This is the best I could find:
http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/sidekit/api/envvar.html#how-to-cut-the-dependency-to-theano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set an environment variable by going to Properties -> Click on the Advanced system settings -> Click on the Environment Variables.

After you install Sidekit, you can simply set the variable. If you are working on a CPU, set the variable as follows.

```
SIDEKIT = ”theano=true,theano_config=gpu,libsvm=true,mpi=false”
```

If you are working on a GPU, you'll need to have `nvcuda.dll` in your system for Sidekit to be imported successfully.